# Generate all possible combinations in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 1000 observations and 1 dummy variable (which takes value of either 0 or 1).

```
example = as.data.frame(rep(1, 1000))
names(example) = "Dummy"
head(example)
  Dummy
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
```

I would like to generate all possible combinations for that "Dummy" variable so that the data frame might look like this:

```
      Dummy.1  Dummy.2  Dummy.3   ... Dummy.2^1000
    1       1        1        1   ...            0
    2       1        1        1   ...            0
    3       1        1        1   ...            0
    4       1        1        1   ...            0
    5       1        1        0   ...            0
    6       1        0        0   ...            0
    .       .        .        .   ...            .
    .       .        .        .   ...            .
    .       .        .        .   ...            .
    1000    1        0        1   ...            0
```

Remember that I have 1000 observations and each observation can take the value of either 0 or 1, so I should have 2^1000 columns.

Comment: If you're considering all combinations, you should end up with 1000^2 columns, right?

Comment: I thought the variable takes only 2 possible values (0 or 1), thus 2 * 1000 = 2000. If the variable takes 1000 possible values, then I might have 1000 * 1000 columns

Comment: For your first number, you have two choices, 0 or 1. For your second number, you have two choices, 0 or 1. If you combine these, you have a total of 2^2 = 4 choices, 00, 01, 10, 11.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just realized that it should be the square. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If you are going to provide an example, wouldn't  `example = as.data.frame(rep(1, 5))` be enough? The same logic applies whether 5 or 1000 and it's more easily understood. Or for that matter, 3 would be enough.

Comment: e.g. `do.call(expand.grid, replicate(3,0:1,simplify=FALSE))` would give you all combinations at 3 levels.

Comment: @goodtimeslim It's actually 2^n combinations, e.g. 2 numbers = 4 choices, 3 = 8, 4 = 16, 5 = 32, 1000 = 1.07e+301

Comment: Echoing @thelatemail, this is 2^1000, not 1000^2. Much bigger!

Comment: I caught that a little while after I posted it, but no one corrected me, so I doubted my correction. Combinations always give me pause.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I have corrected them in the post. Just realised that this might not be possible as the data is too large.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a random sample or something?  There is probably a better approach to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scripted way to do it for 6 observations resulting in a data.frame with 2^6 = 64 columns that cover all permutations of zeros and ones for 6 bits. This method can be scaled up to the limit of available memory.

First create the vectors and add to data.frame as columns:

```
p = as.vector(apply(expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1), 1, paste0, collapse=""))
v1 <- as.numeric(substring(p[1], seq(1,nchar(p[1]),1),   seq(1,nchar(p[1]),1)))
df <- cbind(v1) # this gets the data.frame started right
for (i in 2:length(p)) {
  df <- cbind(df,as.numeric(substring(p[i], seq(1,nchar(p[i]),1), seq(1,nchar(p[i]),1))))
      # assign proper colnames later
}
```

Finally create the column names for the data.frame and insert them:

```
cn = c()
for (i in 1:64) {
  n <- paste0("v",i)
  cn <- c(cn,n)
}
colnames(df) <- cn
```

Almost everything is parameterized -- except to do this for 1000 observations change the 64 in the 2nd step to 1000 and in the first step it will be easiest to expand the series of 0:1,... by cutting and pasting it to length 10, then do that for the 10 10 times and for the resulting 100 another 10 times.

1000 observations will require 1.07150860718626732094842504906e+301 columns by 1000 rows for 1.07150860718626732094842504906e+304 cells at 4-8 bytes each which comes to 4.28603442874506928379370019624e+280 yottabytes at the low end.